# Open new Tab when button is clicked

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

using wicket I want to open a new tab when a button or link is clicked, how can I achieve it?

what I have managed to do is to open it in a pop up like this:

```
 PopupSettings popupSettings = new  PopupSettings("popuppagemap").setLeft(0).setHeight(500).setWidth(500).setHeight(0);

    // Popup example
final Link<Void> setPopupSettings = new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("searchBtn", HomePage.class)
   .setPopupSettings(popupSettings);
```

but this opens it in a new window.

Comment: You need to call some JavaScript. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no problem to open a link in a new tab: just add 'target="_blank"' to the link.

```
final Link<Void> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("link", HomePage.class){
    @Override
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
        super.onComponentTag(tag);
        tag.put("target", "_blank");
    }
};
add(link);
```

Comment: If the tag for the link is an <a> (anchor) tag, you can add the target to the html, no need to override `onComponentTag` in that case.

Comment: Don't need to do it in code unless you want to be able to control *when* it happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a button instead of a link that opens a new tab you can use:

```
html:

<a wicket:id="tabFormViewEmpBut"><button type="button">Click Me!</button></a>
```

And

```
Java wicket:

final Link<Void> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("tabFormViewEmpBut", HomePage.class) {
   @Override
   protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
     super.onComponentTag(tag);
     tag.put("target", "_blank");
   }
};
add(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a function of Wicket but of your browser and HTML in general.

simply add a target tag to your link:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" wicket:id="myCoolLink">My Cool Link</a>
```

What actually happens when the link is clicked will depend on the browser. Before browsers had tabs, this would have opened a new window, now most browsers will open a new tab by default, however, you can't depend on that happening because the feature is optional.